# Xamarin.iOS Rounded corners on UITableViewCell ImageView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, xamarin.ios

I have a UITableCell which has an ImageView. I'm attempting to give that ImageView rounded corners. I have tried the following:

```
    cell.ImageView.ClipsToBounds = true;
    cell.ImageView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
    cell.ImageView.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
    cell.ImageView.Layer.CornerRadius = 20;
```

But this has had no effect. Can anyone explain or demonstrate with a code sample how to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another question ah, but it should work fine like you did, there is a screenshot, so just point where the problem is, then I can help you.

[image]

Or just post more detail code you did, then I maybe can find the problem.

Comment: Ah I think the problem was because I had extended UITableViewCell, I have added the rounded corners code to the constructor of my custom UITableViewCell and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.ImageView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
cell.ImageView.Layer.CornerRadius = 20; 
cell.ImageView.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
```

Try to masks to bounds at the end.

Comment: Hi Evgeny this has had no effect. The image still renders without rounded corners.

Comment: Please try without `cell.ImageView.ClipsToBounds = true;` line of code... just comment it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

## ViewCellRenderer

1. First create your listview

   ```
   namespace  MaxenceTest.Renderers  
       {  
           public  class  MyViewCell  :  ViewCell  
           {  
               public  static  BindableProperty  CornerRadiusProperty  =               BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CornerRadius),  typeof(double),  typeof(MyViewCell),default(double));  
               public  double  CornerRadius  
               {  
                   get  {  return  (double)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);  }  
                   set  {  SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty,  value);  }  
               }  

           public  static  BindableProperty  BackgroundColorProperty  =  BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BackgroundColor),  typeof(Color),  typeof(MyViewCell),  default(Color));  
           public  Color  BackgroundColor  
           {  
               get  {  return  (Color)GetValue(BackgroundColorProperty);  }  
               set  {  SetValue(BackgroundColorProperty,  value);  }  
           }  
       }  
   }
   ```
2. Implements it in your Xamarin iOS project

   ```
   [assembly:  ExportRenderer(typeof(MyViewCell),  typeof(MyViewCellIOS))\]  
   namespace  MaxenceTest.iOS.Renderers  
   {  
       public  class  MyViewCellIOS  :  ViewCellRenderer  
       {  
           public  override  UITableViewCell  GetCell(Cell  item,              UITableViewCell  reusableCell,  UITableView  tv)  
           {  
               UITableViewCell  viewCell  =  base.GetCell(item,  reusableCell,  tv);  
               if(viewCell  !=  null)  
               {  
                   if(item  is  MyViewCell  mycell)  
                   {  
                       UIView  custom  =  new  UIView();  
                       viewCell.ContentView.Layer.BackgroundColor  =                       mycell.BackgroundColor.ToCGColor();  
                       viewCell.ContentView.Layer.CornerRadius  =  new  nfloat(mycell.CornerRadius);  
                   }  
               }  
               return  viewCell;  
           }  
       }  
   }
   ```
3. Use it in xcml

   ```
                   <StackLayout  BackgroundColor="Transparent">  
                       <ListView  
                           x:Name="list"  
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent"  
                           SeparatorColor="Transparent"  
                           SeparatorVisibility="None"  
                           HasUnevenRows="true">  
                           <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
                               <DataTemplate>  
                                   <myControls:MyViewCell  CornerRadius="20"       BackgroundColor="Fuchsia">  
                                       <Grid>  
                                           <Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                                               <RowDefinition  Height="*"/>  
                                           </Grid.RowDefinitions>      
                                           <StackLayout  Margin="10">  
                                               <Label  FontSize="20"  TextColor="White"    FontAttributes="Bold"  Text="{Binding  title}"/>  
                                               <Label  FontSize="15"  TextColor="White"  Text="{Binding  resume}"/>  
                                           </StackLayout>  
                                       </Grid>  
                                   </myControls:MyViewCell>  
                               </DataTemplate>  
                           </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
                       </ListView>  
                   </StackLayout>
   ```
4. Enjoy